# Can I increase the voltage coming out of an IC pin?

Tags: voltage, pcb-design, integrated-circuit

I have a PCB with an IC **TLE8209 - 1E**, the **out1** pin of this IC has a voltage of **11.50 V**. However, I need at least **12 V** to be present in this **out1** pin. Here's a simplified schematic of the PCB with the IC:

[image]

I was thinking if I can add a battery of **1 V** in series with **out1** pin, I can increase the voltage:

[image]

Will this work? And do I have to increase the voltage the **out1** pin of the IC, or I can leave it?

Comment: Are you certain it needs to be at least 12 V? 11.5 V sounds close enough for any 12 V application I can think of.

Comment: @Hearth I'm not sure where the problem is, that's why I'm not changing the IC, I first want to add voltage to it to debug the problem. I have a reference board, and the voltage coming out of out1 pin is 12.36V

Comment: As Hearth indicated, this sounds more like a requirements understanding problem than an actual technical problem. Could you do me (and them) the favour of adding a link to documentation of that "Throttle Actuator Motor" IC in your block diagram? (adding a battery there will very likely **not** help, but make things worse).

Comment: Show us your entire schematic. Putting a battery there is not a tenable solution even if it *would* work, which I can't tell if it would without more information.

Comment: @MarcusMüller it's not an IC, it's actually going directly to the positive terminal of the actuator motor

Comment: Is the VS voltage level (pins 6 & 15) the same on your board and the reference board?  That voltage can be increased if needed.

Comment: @Nedd yes, the VS on both board has the same voltage value

Comment: @JohnSall in that case, we need a full schematic, and type information on that motor. Why would a motor work with 12V but not 11.5 V? That sounds so unlikely, I'd call it "impossible for all practical purposes".

Comment: This is a textbook [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/), which you might like to read about.

Comment: How are you measuring the OUT1 voltage?  If you are only using a simple DVM note that the signal could be pulses from the chip's H-bridge. If available use a scope or a hi-quality DVM with a signal display. There could even be noise on the output signal that may or may not be due to the driver chip.  Also note that the throttle actuator motor usually has a feedback signal to the control system, if the feedback comes to the same PCB you might look into that signal as being a potential source of the problem.

Comment: This is a throttle actuator. They wear out or go stuck or whatever. How do you know the throttle actuator isn't actually mechanically broken? Like broken motor, broken position sensor, plate getting stuck, etc? These things fail all the time especially if the car has turbo and is past 150k-200k miles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

11.5V vs 12V is not a problem. That thing should work with the battery being somewhat drained so the whole device must work from 9-10V motor included. There’s no scenario in which a motor rated at 12V will “stop working” under rated load with just 0.5-1V less on the input.

Whatever you think the problem is - it isn’t. Describe exactly what the problem is: what you think should be happening, what is happening, the schematic, scope traces etc.

Comment: This PCB is actually the PCM of a car, and the car has a DTC error P2118, the code has this explanation : "Throttle actuator control(TAC) throttle motor current - range/performance problem. " so I thought it might had to do with voltage

Comment: @JohnSall Those are rather typical problems. Either the throttle plate is stuck or gets stuck occasionally, or the actuator motor has an open winding, or the throttle plate position sensor is dying or dead. Does the throttle-by-wire work at all, or is the car in limp mode? Is this a Volvo? If it's a Volvo there's more I can tell you.

Comment: It's Hyundai accent 2012, the problem occurred after I opened my ECU with a heat gun, it was sealed off. I think I might damaged a component. The car now cranks but won't start, with the DTC code error I gave above. it was starting before I opened the ECU just fine

Comment: That DTC code is probably not what is important. At “reasonable” ambient temperatures - 20-30C - the car will start without the throttle module even plugged in. The plate’s neutral position allows enough air in to idle. Do the normal troubleshooting: fuel, air, spark. Air is not a problem thanks to the “graceful degradation” mode of the ETM.

Answer (score 0):

If your power supply is 12VDC and you have a 500 mV drop I think you need to review your track design. Maybe your PCB track is too narrow. Try to use a PCB plane instead if you are driving high current through the output. Just for reference, what is your load current?

Comment: the overall current in the PCB is 0.41 amp